# Custom PC No Power

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Alright smart people of the internet. I come to you in desperation. I've been at it for hours and I'm entirely lost. I was one of the lucky few that was able to get their hands on a Asus TUF 3060 OC. Brought it home and realized, damn, it won't fit in my M-ATX case. I thought, no problem, I'll just get a mid-tower, I've been overdo for a new case. Order the Mustex TR400 from Amazon, huge upgrade because it had RGB and we all know RGB makes the computer go faster.

Anyway, remove everything from my M-ATX (except the RAM and CPU) then pop it all into the new case. Read the manuals on how everything should be plugged into the MOBO (audio, power switch, etc.) - nothing happened. I thought, weird, maybe the case is somehow causing a short somewhere. I take out my multi-meter and start testing random pins on the board to see if power was traveling through the board. Yep, received some readings, power is making it to the board.

I transferred everything to my old case, plugged it in - nothing. I thought, the PSU is relatively young and I tested the outlet, outlets good. Did the paperclip test on the PSU, yep got 1 rotation of the fan (thought 1 rotation was kind of odd but took it to mean the PSU was functional). I came to the conclusion, it must be the MOBO.

I drive out to Microcenter to purchase a new MOBO (MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon Max WiFi). Make it back to my place, swap everything to the new MOBO place it in the new case - Nothing. Swap that into the old case - Nothing. I do some research. I find that if a PSU is emitting inconsistent readings, then a MOBO won't turn on. I thought, maybe that would explain the odd readings on the 24 pin MOBO connector and the singular rotation of the PSU fan after the paperclip test.

I go to Microcenter again, purchase a PowerSpec 850W Gold. Come home, carry my broken buddy to a new outlet that I know works 100%, plug everything in - Nothing again. Is my CPU bad??? That would really suck if that was the culprit because it's just over a year old, but I'd imagine lights would at least turn on if my CPU went bad, it just wouldn't POST. I could be wrong though. Any help or guidance or tests to run would be great.

**Parts**

- CPU - AMD 3900X
- GPU - NVIDIA 1660 Ti
- Old MOBO - MSI x470 Gaming Plus
- New MOBO - MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon Max WiFi
- Old PSU - Corsair Vengeance 750M
- Memory - 4x DDR4 8GB Viper 3000MHz
- New Case - Mustex TR400
- Old Case - ???

**What I've tried so far:**

- Tried shorting the power switch pins on the MOBO, still nothing. No lights, sounds, or movement.
- tried removing and replacing the CMOS battery and removing the GPU, still nothing
- I've checked and rechecked my CPU's pins and everything looks fine. No thermal paste on the pins, no bent pins and the arrow is properly aligned.
- RAM has been seated and reseated. I'm down to 2 sticks in the main slots.
- Tested all of the pins in the new PSU 24 pin MOBO plug, all are reading correct voltages

Comment: Any chance your power strip or outlet is bad that feeds the PSU? If you connect nothing but the CPU, one stick or RAM, Motherboard power, maybe 1 fan, and power button, no video card or anything else, will it power on? If not, I would suggest a trip back to Microcenter and get a Power Supply Tester like this one: https://www.microcenter.com/product/508304/kingwin-digital-lcd-power-supply-tester for <$20. Start there, but this really sounds like a connection or power source problem, even if the CPU was bad, it should spin the fan.

Comment: Did you remember the CPU power? Tends to catch people a lot.

Comment: Yep, CPU power is switched on. I'm completely bare bones, like you suggested acejavelin and the power supply is outputting because I pulled up the schematics for a 24 pin MOBO and all the voltages are reading correctly with my multimeter.